# relatively prime solutions of $\phi(x)+\phi(y)=\phi(x+y)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Let $\phi$ denote Euler's totient.

A problem from a book I red required to prove that the equation $\phi(x)+\phi(y)=\phi(x+y)$ has infinitely many solutions.

I solved it: Let's take $x=p$ and $y=2p$, where $p\ge 5$ is prime; easy to check.

Later I started looking for a solution with $\gcd(x,y)=1$, I wrote a program in C that checked many small numbers and gave thousands of examples, but I was unable to spot one particular infinite sequence among them.

**How can we prove that the equation has infinitely many relatively prime solutions ?**

Here is a particular result from the program I wrote, all relatively prime solutions with $1\le x<y<100$:

$(1,2),
(4,5),
(5,16),
(6,19),
(7,38),
(8,17),
(8,77),
(11,16),
(13,14),
(13,20),
(16,35),
(24,41),
(24,53),
(25,26),
(25,32),
(26,29),
(28,37),
(28,65),
(29,40),
(29,64),
(30,89),
(31,86),
(32,55),
(36,89),
(36,97),
(37,50),
(37,56),
(38,47),
(44,85),
(44,89),
(46,79),
(48,97),
(49,62),
(50,91),
(52,77),
(53,88),
(55,92),
(56,89),
(61,80),
(62,83),
(64,77),
(64,95),
(68,91),
(76,77),
(78,97).$

Comment: (30,77) uses up all primes lower than the sqrt of the sum , so it basically can't work for example.

Comment: You can prove the sum can't be prime ( excepting 1,2) fairly easily.

Comment: But I want $x$ and $y$ to be relatively prime, nothing about sum

Comment: Yes well I was mostly pointing out things that still may be helpful to consider ( like things that relate to that their sum must have some prime factor, and it's odd)

Comment: Part of the reason bringing up it can't have $x+y$ prime  is useful, is because up to each being 100, that represents north of a third of all pairs with gcd being 1 ...

Comment: Sorry for spamming but here are the approximate sums you might want to check out: $$\sum_{m=1}^{z} \left (\pi(m+z)-\pi(2m)\right)$$ and $$\sum_{m=1}^{z} \phi(m)\lfloor{\frac{z}{m}}\rfloor$$

Comment: If $r$ is a prime number such that $p:=3r-8$ and $q:=3r+4$ are also prime, then the pair $(p/2q)$ is a solution. Hence [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H) conjecture implies that there infinite many coprime solutions. This is not yet a proof since it is based on an open conjecture , but I doubt that we can get a better result.